# Chrome RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when using jQuery $.map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, web-applications, browser

I'm testing a web application for my employers which involves retrieving a large amount of data from the server.  The data is returned as a JSON object using the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function, containing large quantities of sub-objects which I convert to arrays using jQuery's [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) function as follows

```
data_points = $.map(result.data.LotsOfIt, function(value, ndx){
              return value;
          }); //Throws Maximum call stack size exceeded with large data set.
```

This seems to be exhausting Chromes stack size limit, everytime I run this function Chrome will throw a **RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded**.  If I reduce the amount of data returned, it works just fine.  What's interesting is that FireFox and IE9 will process the larger data set just fine, but I thought Chrome had a larger stack size limit than either of these browsers so I would've expected them both to fail as well.  Has anyone else encountered this problem?  Is there a workaround? Or will I have to update my code to limit the amount of data returned in order to avoid this error?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so after doing some reading, I suspect that the issue had something to do with a recursive call within the $.map implementation that was causing the Chrome browser stack to overflow.  I had to rework the code to iterate over the collection of returned JSON objects manually and in a non-recursive manner.  After refactoring the code to use $.map against the entire collection at cone, the stack overflow issue no longer appeared.