# jQuery catch "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, chromium

I have a page, that works fine in FF and IE. However, chrome throws

```
jquery.min.js:2    Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

It's because of trying to process a lot of data (see [Chrome RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when using jQuery $.map](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11783575/910868)).

Is it possible to `catch` the error, so that the whole page's javascript doesn't hang? Or do I have to reduce the amount of data for chrome.

Comment: I doubt it has to do with trying to process a lot of data; that other question has no answers, and I doubt it was the problem there too. You posted no code, so it's impossible to say what's going on.

Comment: There's no recursion in the code. I think that infinite recursion would crash other browser as well. The fact is, that even ie7 is dealing better than webkit in this situation. Also the question is not about helping me, but about being able to catch the `RangeError`. I don't understand the downvotes...

Comment: You didn't post any code. You *say* there's no recursion, but that's obviously the most likely cause of the problem.

Comment: Well, I am not asking to get a direct solution for my problem, but rather to see, whether it's possible, to catch the error on global scope. That's the question, if you read the last paragraph.

Comment: @PetrMarek Sure: [`try..catch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch) or [`window.onerror`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onerror). But, what are you hoping to get out of that other than a solution to the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't support Tail Recursion. You're probably calling a function from a function from a function until it blows. (Please post some code to show what you're doing).

Use a **setTimeout** between 'iterations'. This way you don't block the UI or blow up the stack.

Comment: Simple iteration won't ever exhaust the stack anyway.

Comment: @Pointy Correct! I didn't mean simple iterations. Updated my answer to explain it better.

Comment: I'm getting this error on following code for click event on close button
    jQuery(this).attr("href", "#");
    jQuery(this).trigger("click");
    jQuery(this).attr("href", "#!");